# VideoView inside DialogFragment is transparent while preparing

Tags: android, surfaceview, android-videoview

I have an issue and not sure how to fix it. On my `DialogFragment` I have a `VideoView` which loads a video from web. The `VideoView` is inside on a `FragmentLayout` and over it there is a `ImageView` acting like a play button. 
When `OnPreparedListener` is firing, I set `seek(1)` so the video is displayed inside the `VideoView`.

The problem is that while the video is preparing, the `VideoView` is transparent and the parent activity layout is visible. If I set `setZOrderOnTop(true)` then there is no transparent background but the `ImageView` is not displayed overlaying it.

Any way of having both, no transparent background and the image over the VideoView?

Comment: Did you find any solution?